# C# Arrays and Loops

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop

What am I doing wrong in my loop? I can only get the first iteration of the loop but not the rest. My output is:

```
1 NAND 0 = 1
```

I'm missing the other four?

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] array1 = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };
        int[] array2 = { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 };
        int i;
        int answer;

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (array1[i] == 1 && array2[i] == 1)
            {
                answer = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                answer = 1;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0} NAND {1} = {2}", array1[i], array2[i], answer);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Place `Console.ReadLine()` outside loop body. Currently you have to press Enter after every iteration (console output).

Comment: You have a ReadLine in the loop, have you tried pressing Enter after the first line has been printed?

Comment: @RomanDoskoch Why didn’t you post your answer as an answer? Comments cannot be accepted as answer and therefore this question officially has no answers.

Comment: @SymboLinker, thanks, answer has been added

Comment: I'd write it as `answer = ((array1[i] + array2[i]) == 2) ? 0 : 1;` or `answer = ((array1[i] == 1) && (array2[i] == 1)) ? 0 : 1;` using the [Ternary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) operator.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

At the end of the every iteration you need to press Enter to continue loop.

Just move this statement outside the loop body:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (array1[i] == 1 && array2[i] == 1)
    {
        answer = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        answer = 1;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0} NAND {1} = {2}", array1[i], array2[i], answer);
}

Console.ReadLine(); // now it's here (outside loop body)
```

Also the code can be changed a bit:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array1 = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };
    int[] array2 = { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 };
    int answer;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        answer = (array1[i] + array2[i]) == 2 ? 0 : 1; // ternary operator

        Console.WriteLine($"{array1[i]} NAND {array2[i]} = {answer}"); // string interpolation (C# 6+)
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```